# How to: Show a colored portion of an otherwise uncolored background in a div or behind and img?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say on a web page there's a black and white background that is a picture of a landscape or city. Now, in a `div` (whose location does not have to be fixed) on the page, you see the background in color, but only the portion of the background that is the size of the `div`, i.e. the `div` serves as a "window" into a colored view of the otherwise black and white background.

**Is this possible using just basic web technologies (e.g. HTML, CSS, JS)?** I gave some thought to just making the background of the `div` the colored portion of the background that the `div` is covering, but assuming the site is screen size responsive, this would not look too great when the site shifts to a smaller screen size - the colored image would not be aligned with the image any longer.

**Any ideas? I appreciate any and all!**

Edit - an idea: Is there a CSS property that I can use to blur/darken the entire area of the background except for that which is covered by/contained in the div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is offset using negative margins equal to the absolute top and left position of the parent div with `overflow: hidden;`.

I think this is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/w17x32dg/2/

```js
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0,
    y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0,
    y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

var image;

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    image = document.getElementById('image');
    
    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
        image.style.marginLeft = -(x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        image.style.marginTop = -(y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('color').onmousedown = function () {
    _drag_init(this);
    return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
}
#color {
    cursor: move;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/BgewSni.jpg" />
<div id="color">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3Ec3jhz.jpg" id="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you @user2570380. Would it be easy to disable the user's ability to move the #color div and leave the only moving up to the div's responsiveness to the screen size (e.g. the div only moves when it shifts around per a responsive template, like bootstrap)?

Comment: I haven't used the framework, but try resizing the width of the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/w17x32dg/3/